# Understanding Uniformly Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences, sequence-of-function

I was reading a proof in my notes that we went over in class.
It says let ${f_n}$ be Cauchy in $C(X)$ where $C(X)$ is the space of bounded and continuous functions.  This translates to ${f_n}$ being uniformly Cauchy in the sense of Rudin's Theorem 7.8.

No justification is given in my notes, and I don't understand how $f_n$ being Cauchy in $C(X)$ translates to $f_n$ being uniformly Cauchy.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space of bounded continuous functions is (presumably) equipped with the sup norm, so given $\epsilon > 0$ there is $N$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\sup_{x \in X} |f_n (x) - f_m (x)| < \epsilon \text{ for all } m, n > N. \label{1}
\end{equation}
For all $x \in X$, we have
\begin{equation*}
|f_n (x) - f_m (x)| \leq \sup_{x \in X} |f_n (x) - f_m (x)| < \epsilon \text{ for all } m, n > N.
\end{equation*}
Since $N$ is independent of $x$, this is exactly what we mean by uniformly Cauchy.

Comment: Great.  Thanks, this really helped.